# A way to show HTML-based dialog to everyone

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to show a dialog with .showModalDialog() based on HTML template HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile() to everyone, not only editors of the spreadsheet?

I have [a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zjSYxw8Q8rWA5D6mupFwv4oN76-D8bIvV2kHSTd8s70/edit#gid=1616508651) where I'd like to present data from in HTML prepared template but it shows only to editors. Is this a well-known issue?

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not positive what you are asking, but I'll take a couple stabs at it.

A) If you mean, 'can I show my sheet and dialog to someone without them being an editor?', your question makes little sense and the answer is no. In order to show the modal dialog you made as an add-on to a spread sheet, you must use the spreadsheet.

B) If you mean, 'can I use my add-on in a different spreadsheet than the one it was developed on?', the answer is, yes! You can publish an add-on on the google web store. When in the add-on IDE, just go to the 'Publish' tab and click 'Publish as a Spreadsheet add-on'.

If you are part of a company google account (your.name@company.com is your gmail address), you can publish so only members of you company can use your script.

C) I believe this is what you must have meant, which is "Can I have my dialog/html page devoid entirely of my Spreadsheet, but using data from my spreadsheet?"

The answer to this is also yes! Instead of using 'Script Editor' inside of your spread sheet. Go to your GDrive, click 'New', and make a new script. This script is called a Standalone Script, and it has slightly different rules from an add-on.

It must use a doGet() function to get its HTML page most importantly. However, it can use things like SpreadsheetApp and DriveApp, just like an add-on. It will not be able to use .getActiveSheet, but it will be able to do .getSheetById/Name().

For more details, you can look here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone

I hope this helped.